# How to display three different sized columns in HTML

Tags: html

I am creating a HTML webpage, and I will have three columns on the page. One sidebar, one main page, and one sidebar on the left side as well.

http://postimg.org/image/5sd87ktbf/00734539/

In the end, I want it to look like the link above.

My code is now looking like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="    ">Hotels</a></td>
        <td rowspan=3>" text "></td>
        <td><a href="     ">Movieland >/a</td>
    <tr>
<table>
```

I feel a bit off track, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong with the code you provided, at a very basic level.  You may want to spend some time working at an HTML tutorials before venturing in to trying to build a website.  w3schools.org has some good, basic tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Just give it a width with CSS.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.content {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="sidebar">Sidebar</td>
    <td class="content">Content</td>
    <td class="sidebar">Sidebar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use new property of CSS called [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to position them align

style

```
<style>
.container{
    display: flex;
}
</style>
```

html

```
<div class="container">
<aside>
    <h3>Sidebar</h3>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus laudantium sint, id, rerum eaque cum, repellat quis ut aliquam maxime odio expedita illo aperiam ex, quasi accusamus enim voluptatum obcaecati.
    </p>

</aside>

<main>
    <h3>Main content</h3>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt error, officia fugit autem accusamus voluptas cupiditate facere labore maxime, eveniet sequi placeat iure fugiat! Ea omnis porro sunt dicta similique.
    </p>
</main>

<aside>
    <h3>Next sidebar</h3>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita, officiis perferendis voluptas ut accusantium placeat atque quos impedit sapiente minus officia molestias reiciendis doloremque veritatis quod. Soluta, temporibus dolor.
    </p>
</aside>

</div>
```

you can read more about flexbox [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)